# Using an apply function to select a window of cells from a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, moving-average

Given a matrix:

```
m <- matrix(rep(1:10,10),10,20)
```

Is it possible to use an `apply` function to move around the matrix and select a window of cells (3 columns and 3 rows big - 9 cells in size), where every cell is the focal cell of the 9 in the window?

As my desired window is 3x3 cells, I can pad out the matrix with 1 row and column of NAs at the edges so that the window will function on any given cell that contains a number:

```
m <- cbind(matrix(,nrow(m),1),m,matrix(,nrow(m),1))
m <- rbind(matrix(,1,ncol(m)),m,matrix(,1,ncol(m)))
```

When the 9 values are subset, I wish to calculate the mean and sd for each time that the cell is in the center of the window of 9 cells and output these single value to a new respective matrices (one for mean and one for sd).

I have done this manually using nested `for` loops, but over big matrices, it is a slow process. I have not managed to find a function that creates a window over both rows and columns, hence trying to figure this out.

Here is my `for` loop example:

```
m <- matrix(rep(1:10,10),10,20)
##The number of cells on each dimension of the window
window <- 3
pad <- (window-1)/2
##Row padding
m.pad <- rbind(matrix(,pad,ncol(m)),m,matrix(,pad,ncol(m)))
##Column padding
m.pad <- cbind(matrix(,nrow(m.pad),pad),m.pad,matrix(,nrow(m.pad),pad))
##Note real data dimensions in the padded matrix
maxrow <-nrow(m.pad)-pad
maxcol <- ncol(m.pad)-pad
##Create output matrices
mean_values <- matrix(,nrow(m),ncol(m))
sd_values <-  matrix(,nrow(m),ncol(m))
##Moving window to create mean and sd
for (i in (pad+1):maxrow)
{
  for (j in (pad+1):maxcol)
  {
    ##Subset out the window into a vector, 
    ##take mean and sd and put into new matrix
    mean_values[(i-pad),(j-pad)] <- mean(as.vector(
      m.pad[(i-pad):(i+pad),(j-pad):(j+pad)]),na.rm=TRUE)
    sd_values[(i-pad),(j-pad)] <- sd(as.vector(
      m.pad[(i-pad):(i+pad),(j-pad):(j+pad)]),na.rm=TRUE)
  }
}
```

My desired outputs are shown in `mean_values` and `sd_values`.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I understand the window selection, but once you have your list of windows (basically a list of 3x3 matrixes) what do you want to calculate the mean and sd of? Is that the mean and sd of all the elements within one window (repeated for all the windows)?

Comment: Yes for each 3x3 window, I wish to obtain an equally weighted mean and sd from all 9 values in the window (ignoring NAs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
subset_values <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(m),function(i) t(sapply(1:ncol(m),function(j) m.pad[i:(i+2),j:(j+2)]))))
mean_values <- matrix(apply(subset_values,1,mean,na.rm=T),nrow = nrow(m),byrow = T)
sd_values <- matrix(apply(subset_values,1,sd,na.rm=T),nrow = nrow(m),byrow = T)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have changed the reproducible matrix in the question to make it easier to understand if the output is correct. Using your code on the new matrix followed by `out <- t(matrix(mean_values,nrow=10,ncol=20))`, unfortunately the output values don't represent the mean of the focal cell and the surrounding window cells. It looks close though!

Comment: @JPD : Maybe I did not understand the problem correctly. You told that you can do this using `for` loop. Will you please share your expected output? That will help me to get you. Btw, are those subsets matching to your desired output?

Comment: I have added my `for` loop code to the question, and you should be able to reproduce the outputs. I think your subsets are working correctly, and it may just be that I've put the values your code produces into a matrix incorrectly?

Comment: @JPD : I made changes according to your `m` & `m.pad` matrices. I think now it's ok.